# jQuery checkbox question

Tags: jquery

I have inherited the following code snippet:

```
<div id="topbox">
    <h3>
        <div class="compare_link">Compare Products</div> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="compare_123" name="chkcompare[]" value="123" />
    </h3>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is:

I want to find all h3 selectors that have compare_link and HTML checkbox as children and move the checkbox down 10 pixels.

I know I can find checkboxes with jQuery, but can I do this if the sibling is compare_link?

I don't have access to some of the code which is why I can't move the checkbox down myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this necessarily. You can do this with CSS. However, browser support may vary.

```
h3 > div.compare_link + input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

If you want to use jQuery it takes CSS selectors. So the following should work:

```
$('h3 > div.compare_link + input[type="checkbox"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you just asking for the selector?

```
$('h3 > .compare_link + :checkbox')
```

Comment: Good use of direct child selector.

Comment: Yes, because once the elements are selected, then I should be able to set the css.  What did you mean by your comment about the direct child selector?

Comment: Yes, because once the elements are selected, then I should be able to set the css.  What did you mean by your comment about the direct child selector?

Comment: sorry about the 2x post, I wasn't done commenting.  Did you mean ".compare_link + :checkbox"?

Answer (score 0):

For the most flexibility use:

```
$('h3 div.compare_link').siblings('input:checkbox')
```

This selects all checkboxes that are siblings of divs with the `compare_link` class. The `div`  with the `compare_link` class must be descendants of an `h3` tag.

The advantage is that this works even the checkbox is move infront of the div or another div is placed in between or if the `compare_link` div is wrapped in another div etc...